# Session timeout not working in embedded Jetty

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-jetty

I am working on a Spring Boot project which uses Jetty embedded.  I am trying to set the session timeout.  I have the property set in `application.properties`:

```
server.servlet.session.timeout=60
```

I am using `SessionRegistry` to debug and I can see that none of my sessions are expired even when their last action is older than 1 minute.  I also note that `SessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(..)` is never called.

I have also tried setting the timeout manually in a `ServletContextInitializer`

```
servletContext.setSessionTimeout(60);
```

but I get an error, because the method is not implemented:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext$Context does not define
    or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void setSessionTimeout(int)'
    of interface javax.servlet.ServletContext.
```

Version:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:jar:2.6.7:compile
```

I am obviously missing something or misunderstanding something.  For one thing, it seems that expireNow() might not be called when a session is timedout.  From what I can see, expireNow() is only called when there are too many concurrent sessions.

How does the session timeout process work in Spring/Embedded Jetty?