# What is the best way to track user login/logout on a Spring Boot web application?

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-jetty

I work on a Spring Boot (v2.6.7) app which uses Embedded Jetty as the web server.  I wish to track user login/logout, but it is not a simple case of tracking visits to a login/logout page as these are not used.  We have sessions enabled, however some callers do not use their existing session and just create a new one.

I have been looking at using the `SessionRegistry` and recording a logout when all of a user's sessions are removed, but I am not sure if it is the best approach for our use case. (Particularly as I am also having issue with the sessions not expiring - see my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76970692/session-timeout-not-working-in-embedded-jetty) about this specific approach).

What is the best way to track user login/logout on a Spring Boot application?

Comment: Spring Security fires events for succesful login and logout, which you can listen to using an `@EventListener` or `ApplicationListener`. The same for the session timeout events you can listen to them in the same way (and act upon).

Comment: Thanks.  I will look again when I am back at work tomorrow.  One thing I noticed though is that `@Override
 public void onApplicationEvent(AbstractSessionEvent event)` was never called in my session registry implementation as I put a breakpoint on it.  (Note that `registerNewSession(String sessionId, Object principal)` is called so it is wired correctly.)

Comment: That has nothing to do with the session registy. Session timeouts are handled by the session listener which needs to be registered. The session registry has nothing to do with that. Also you shouldn't be listening to those high level events but rather the specific ones so you can do what you want/need to do.

Comment: Ok, but SessionRegistry implements ApplicationListener<AbstractSessionEvent> so I still think it should be called.  I know my registry is configured because I hit the registerNewSession method.

Comment: What has this to do with your session registry, you want to register login/logout. You are focussing on the wrong things.

Comment: Because we don't have explicit login/logout on the application and so I am looking at tracking a logout as when all of a user's sessions are expired. (This may not be the best approach, which is why I asked the question).Even if I am focusing on the wrong things, I still would like to know why the session timeouts in Jetty do not flow to the `SessionRegistry`.  As a workaround I have injected the `SessionRegistry` into a `SessionListener` and I call `removeSessionInformation(..)` directly.  Thanks

Comment: Because, as I stated before, the events are fired by a `SessionListener` which you need to register. Which will fire those events.

Comment: I see it now, but it was surprising that session timeouts are not automatically linked to the session registry to me.